# "No item found" empty list after adding a new Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

After severall search, maybe without the right english terms, I come here to find an answer to my problem.

I have a theme that I created on my website, everything is working perfectly for the last 6 months.

I also have a custom post type to add some twitch channel on my website and display them.

Yesterday, I created a new custom post type to write some fast news so just the minimal content : title, content, author and revisions.

But when I add this one to my website, the Posts, Streams, News and Pages list become empty with a "not found" message even when there is some content with this post type.

Like this : [image: Empty list]

I think I already had this bug a long time ago but I can't remember how to fix it.

I tried to desactivate my every plugin one by one but the bug was still there.

Here is the code of my Custom Post Type (created with GenerateWP to save a lot of time) :

```
if ( ! function_exists('news_post') ) {

function news_post() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'News', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'News', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent News:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'All News', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New News', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Add News', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'New News', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit News', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Update News', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'View News', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Search News', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into News', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this News', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'News list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'News list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter News list', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'News', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'News Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', ),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => true,        
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'news_post', 0 );

}
```

Any idea about how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing there is registering a new post type called "post_type" change this name to something else - such as:

`register_post_type( 'fast_news', $args );`

See if that works for you?

Comment: You know what? I am just stupid. You found the problem I had with my other Custom Post Type the first time and I just didn't change it on my saved snippet but just changed it in the function.php... Thank you, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Note that as I got the *exact* same issue as in your screenshot (counter of items showed items, but NO items are shown in the list/table, not even my own).

Turned out that the custom theme had a hidden "feature" ..

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order');
    function my_change_sort_order($query){
        if(is_archive()):
           //Set the order ASC or DESC
           $query->set('meta_key', 'score');
           //Set the orderby
           $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        endif;    
    };
```

which essentially adds a 'score' fieldname requirement in the SQL query. and thus will result in zero results.